# LLVM 3.5 fails to link

Tags: llvm

When compiling with the experimental LLVM3.5 libraries link the following link errors appear:

> /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o): In function
>   `llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int)': (.text+0x85b):
>   undefined reference to`setupterm'
>   /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o): In function
>   `llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int)': (.text+0x87a):
>   undefined reference to`tigetnum'
>   /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o): In function
>   `llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int)': (.text+0x888):
>   undefined reference to`set_curterm'
>   /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o): In function
>   `llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int)': (.text+0x890):
>   undefined reference to`del_curterm'

The link command line was generated with `llvm-config`, so why is this failing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`llvm-config` is not adding the link option for the `Terminfo` library. Add

```
-ltinfo
```

To link in the library and all should be well.

Comment: A lot of the LLVM tutorials suggest adding `--system-libs` to the use of `llvm-config`, So I preferred the answer from @xl4times.  Your answer is also correct, but I think folks linking against LLVM should make use of llvm-config.

Comment: I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo`

Answer (score 15):

Add `llvm-config --system-libs` in link option

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo` do you have any idea on this?